# Oracle SQL not seeing query columns in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an `ORA-00904: "XSRM"."RATER_PERSON_ID": invalid identifier` on the `xsrm.rater_person_id` in the subquery. Is this a bug, because the query works fine if I take out the subquery and `select xsrm.rater_person_id`?

```
select xsrm.person_id,
       xsrm.member_id,
       xsrm.rater_person_id,
       xses.date_sent       
from   apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_ratee_members xsrm,
       apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_emails_sent   xses
where  xsrm.reason = '$X$'
and    xsrm.project_id = 1
and    xses.parent_type (+) = 'R'   -- Ratee member
and    xses.parent_id (+) = xsrm.member_id 
and    0 <
(
   select sum(decode(xsa.answer, null, 1, 0))
   from   apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_questions xsq
   left   outer join apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_answers xsa  
   on     xsa.question_id = xsq.question_id
   and    xsa.person_id = xsrm.person_id 
   and    xsa.rater_person_id = xsrm.rater_person_id
   where  xsq.questionnaire_id = 1 
   and    xsq.required_flag = 'Y' 
)
```

This also fails similarly:

```
select xsrm.person_id,
       xsrm.member_id,
       xsrm.rater_person_id,
       xses.date_sent       
from   apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_ratee_members xsrm   
left   outer join apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_emails_sent xses
on     xses.parent_id = xsrm.member_id
and    xses.parent_type = 'R'   -- Ratee member
and    xses.email_event_id = :p_email_event_id
where  xsrm.reason = '$X$'
and    xsrm.project_id = 1
and    0 <
(
   select sum(decode(xsa.answer, null, 1, 0))
   from   apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_questions xsq
   left   outer join apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_answers xsa  
   on     xsa.question_id = xsq.question_id
   and    xsa.person_id = xsrm.person_id 
   and    xsa.rater_person_id = xsrm.rater_person_id
   where  xsq.questionnaire_id = 1 
   and    xsq.required_flag = 'Y' 
)
```

I only recently started fiddling with ansi sql instead of Oracle outer joins.

`apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_ratee_members` structure:

```
"member_id","project_id","ratee_group_id","person_id","rater_person_id","verifier_person_id","reason","rater_level","position_number","verifier_level"
```

Comment: whats the structure of `apex_ebs_extension.xxpay_survey_ratee_members` ?

Comment: I see no reason for this to fail. Of course all fields from the tables in the FROM clause must be known in the WHERE clause. So I don't understand how you can access the field in the SELECT clause and it runs fine, but when using it in the WHERE clause too, it fails. Is this the real query without any changes; not even regarding upper/lower caps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this with my own tables in Oracle 11g and got the same error. Oracle is obviously not able to use a column from an outer query in the **ON clause** of a join in a subquery.

This sure looks like a bug to me, because this is a correlated subquery and Oracle seems not to completely treat is as such.